# My workflow automatically jumps to the end of all of the steps. How can I fix this?

Tags: 2010, workflow

I am working in SharePoint Designer 2010. I have created workflows in the past that are set up to run when an InfoPath Form has been submitted to a library. In the past, they have ran properly. However, suddenly the workflow does not completed  (but isn't listed as incomplete/error on the workflow settings on the item within the library).

The workflow consists of validating the correct steps have been taken.

For example, the first three steps are as follows:

**Step 1:**

```
Set Variable path

then Set Variable: Sent to No
```

**Step 2:**

```
If Current Item: Test One equals blank

and Current Item: Test Two equals blank

and Current Item: Test Three equals blank 

  Email Current Item: Test One Email

  then Email: Current Item: Created By

  then Set Variable:Sent to  Yes
```

**Step 3**

```
If Current Item: Test One equals TRUE

and Current Item: Test Two equals blank

and Current Item: Test Three equals blank

  Email Current Item: Test Two

  then Set Variable: Sent to Yes
```

The workflow behaves properly for Step 1 and 2. However, even if Current Item: Test One equals TRUE, an email is never sent to Current Item: Test Two.

Any insight would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to be concise but there are several things you need to check (or confirm):

1. How is the workflow being launched?  Sounds like you have it set for a new item, but it is turned on for when an item is modified?  Or are you launching it manually?
2. It sounds as if the third step conditional is never met.  I would be careful using 'is blank' with flag values. I assume these are yes/no fields?  If so then the initial work flow IE Step 2 would work, but once it saves, your flag fields are no longer blank, they are assigned a false value. Therefore, your step 3 may never work because test 2 and 3 are not blank.  Remove those two branches and see if it fires off the test 2 email after test 1 is flagged true.

If number 2 is your issue, then rephrase your logic to something like test two not equal TRUE.

Comment: 1. The workflow is being launched automatically when a new item is submitted and when an item is modified.

Comment: Rewrote the workflow to remove the 'is blank' option and replaced with "not equals TRUE", "not equals FALSE" and "not equals DEFER."  I am not receiving any emails now.

Comment: Show me a sample, I'm not sure I'm following what you were doing.  Are 'Test One', 'Test Two', etc Boolean values (Yes or no, true or false) or are they choice fields (if choice, list choices)?

Answer (score 0):

If those are check boxes you are evaluating, unselected would be false not blank. Try updating the values to false and see if that gets you the results you expect.